# React Route causes to class change

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

I want to use same component in another page. One of it on homepage and another one is on category page.

----- HEADER className="popular-header" -----
----- BODY ---------------------

**Homepage css folder**

```
.popular-header {
 display: flex;
 @blabla
}
```

But problem is header shouldnt visible this time and also i will change some button colors in body.
So what i tried is i changed popular-header css like this in its local folder.

**CategoryPage css folder**

```
.popular-header {
 display: none;
}
```

So when i go to category page everything is fine, my header is not there. But when i come back to homepage also my homepage header is gone. Because my class has overriden by that (none). If there was only header part that i want change I could pass props and make it conditionally rendered. But there is also some classes i want change. It is so weird. Two different pages but they concanate each other i guess some SPA issues. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a component named `PopularHeader`, define a prop name `style` (or something like `extraStyle` if you want to)

```
const PopularHeader = ({ style }) => {
    <View className="popular-header" style={{...style}}/>
}
```

and you have the normal css class

```
.popular-header {
    display: flex;
}
```

Normalluy you call you component like this:

```
<PopularHeader />;
```

When you route to another page and you want the header to disappear, simply:

```
<PopularHeader style={{ display: none }}/>;
```

Comment: Yes that was what i thinking about. Because there is no another choice. Thank you for answer.

Comment: " Two different pages but they concanate each", this is because CSS combines to one big pile even though you put them in different css file, unless you wrap them with a unique ID. So I guess your other choice is to add an id to each page and override the css with `#anotherPage.popular-header`

Comment: Oh yes thanks it worked like that. I thought about giving id to same class but class with id had more specifity so it was always overriding only class tag. Now i am giving #anotherPage to main div and playing with its classes.

Answer (score 0):

CSS styles are global, so any component will have access to them no matter what file they are in.  Try using a third-party css or js to css library, or you can change the files to fileName.module.css and import classes from that file.  You'll then have to label each className to {classes.style} and should now be unique to their respective components.

```
import classes from './fileName.module.css'
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes i know module css but it is not what i want. If i use module.css on homepage i cant reach to the same class in category class and i cant make it none. I want to play with same class but it shouldnt be changed in another component. I want to use same component with different class styles.